# RestAssured Test with AsciiDoc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest-assured

I need create a AsciiDoc documents but i dont know how in RestAssured this is my code:

```
@Test
public void getLogout() throws ApiException {

    given()
            .standaloneSetup(controller)
            .header("principal", "admin")
            .header("authorization", "authtoken")
            .accept("application/json")
            .when()
            .post(REST_REQUEST_PATH)
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .statusLine("200");
}
```

My controller is like this, i need generated a documentation with RestDocs:

```
@PostMapping(value = Constants.LOGOUT_URL)
public String logout (HttpServletRequest request) throws ApiException {

    String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authHeader != null) {
        try {
            String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString();
        }
    }
    return Utils.convertDateTime();
}
```

Comment: The provided information is insufficient, do you happen to have any other detail ? a link, cURL command, postman screenshot ?

Comment: What I want to do is add AsciiDoc to my test, I add the controller if it requires something else, just let me know, Thanks

Comment: I add this code but take me a NullPointerException:  .apply(this.documentationHandler.document(responseFields(fieldWithPath("date").description("Fecha de entrega de la respuesta."))));